# Limiting File Path Exposure Using NGINX, uwsgi and Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am using Centos as my OS and I successfully ran my Flask gallery_app on it using uwsgi.

My Flask gallery_app basically is a gallery you upload images to and view them as well as download. The app is working fine and nginx is serving it well. 
The way I am serving images is using flask's:

```
send_from_directory
```

which I have implemented inside route /image

```
@app.route('/image/<path:img_path>')
def image(img_path):
    head, tail = os.path.split(img_path)
    return send_from_directory(head, tail)
```

My app structure is as this:

```
gallery_app
 |_app.py
 |_config.py
 |_templates
 |_models
 |_views
 |_static
 |_**uploads**
```

My application in the OS is sitting on:

```
 /var/www/gallery_app
```

When I upload a file to **uploads** directory I save the path as:

```
uploads/category/filename.png
```

When I want to display the image in flask as

```
<img src="DOMAIN.com/image/uploads/category/filename.png">
```

I get the error that file does not exist. When I do:

`<img src="DOMAIN.com/image/home/user/var/www/gallery_app/uploads/category/filename.png">`

things work normally. What should I do to hide the app location? I tried moving the **uploads** directory to *home/user* and store the full path as */home/user/uploads/category/filename.png* and it works. clearly the application looks in root */* is there a way to make the app or server look inside */var/www/gallery_app/uploads* without exposing the full path to the client?

I tried adding:
 `root /var/www/gallery_app` in server block in nginx but did not work, What am I missing? If I am not understanding this correctly if you can direct me to a resource I can read to understand this

Comment: Where's your "static" folder or have you overridden this in app.py ?

Comment: ah yes; I forgot to write it down but it is there; but I am not uploading to it. However the files I read off it are actually read url_for('static', filename='image')